# What is the right approach to bind jpa beans to cancelable form?

Tags: java, web-applications, jpa

If I use JPA entities in my web-app, what is best approach to bind multiple linked jpa entities to one form in case if it is cancellable (as almost all of them are)?
I.e., you have jpa classes Person and Document, and Person maps as @OneToMany to Document, and a form that maps to Person and have an editable table that maps to inner Documents. In case if you open existing Person in this form and edit one of it's Documents, what is the best approach to bind these entities to a form in a way that you could be ensured that canceled form will rollback all changes made to beans?
How do you solve this problem in your projects?

UPDATE. I'm trying to figure out if there are any acceptable solutions or everybody use their own approach, or is the case so untrivial and therefore is so rare?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*HEAVILY EDITED FROM ORIGINAL ANSWER*

It depends on the requirements of the application.

Generally, you don't update the JPA model until the user completes the task.

In a simple CRUD web-app, this would be when they submit the form data - if they cancel the action, then the form data is never submitted. Whether the JPA model is 'tightly bound' to the submitted form data is irrelevent in this scenario.

Comment: So to achieve the goal in first scenario I should use client-side scripting (like GWT) instead of server-side (like Vaadin)?

And to solve the problem in second scenario I'm anyway forced to implement my own logic, or is there any frameworks/patterns to do it?

Comment: > forced to implement my own logic <

I mean - I'm not gaining any more benefits of binding to JPA in complex scenarios?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with GWT or Vaadin - I was trying to answer your question broadly. The JPA is just about binding java objects to persistent storage with the 'active record' approach - the technology that binds a UI to a JPA-enabled object is a separate thing. If you want a more informed answer about the best UI/web framework for handling your requirements you might want to post a new question.

Comment: Created new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855792/jpa-bound-cancelable-complex-forms-best-framework

I want to preserve this question open in case if there will be more answers with any solutions

Comment: I've massively simplified my answer here

Comment: Now I see your point, I think it's really the only approach to use cancelable multiple forms.

Comment: >>if they cancel the action, then the form data is never submitted.<< Actually, if I merge the bean each time I have to render the form (or something happens on the form), I have already my jpa model updated, so just not pressing cancel button won't help in such cases.